# How to read contents of html textbox and saving it to txt file using node js

Tags: html, node.js, express, node.js-stream

I am learning Node.js scripting.

I want to read input-text from textbox in html page with an option `submit`, it should save the content to .txt file using node.js (using POST/GET)

Comment: Is there anything you already have tried?

Comment: Submit your html form to an API which receives form data and stores in txt file. This is what we can tell when you just post a question. Post your code so that anyone can edit.

Answer (score 0):

your Node.js server should not care about the origin of the data (if it comes from textbox or any other html element).

This answer should give you a clue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4296402/418947

In the node app.post function you will use file system api [Node file api docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) to save the data to your .txt file.

Comment: Thanks, i have changed my solution...!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your templating engine is `ejs`,

Your **View** page (which consists the textbox) would look like,

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  form(name="frmTest", method="get" action="/myform")
    div.input
      input(type="text", name="mytext")
    div.actions
      input(type="submit", value="add")
```

And in the **router** you can get the textbox value using the `query` parameter of the request object like this,

```
router.get('/myform', function(req, res){ 
    var myText = req.query.mytext;
    res.send('Your Text:' +myText); 
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If my post helped you in resolving your issue, Can you please mark it answered?